# Managing pages without CMS in Django?

Tags: django, content-management-system

I'm very new to Django so please bear with me.

My impression is that if I use a full fledge CMS like Django-CMS then I wouldn't be able to incorporate other apps like Cartridge, Django-Celery, etc. If it's correct, then is there a nice way to manage posts/pages without a full fledge CMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not true :) You can use any third party app, and also your own application modules with Django-CMS. It's very flexible and easy to extend. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Right. Say if I want to integrate AskBot into Django-CMS, then would I need to align the user auth? I don't know what else will also need to be aligned, but would this not be a large job since each does things differently?

Comment: I've never used AskBot, but like most Django apps, you'll have to hook the URL patterns up somewhere. Since patterns are matched in order, you could just add AskBot's URLs before Django-CMS's URL pattern and it should work. Now, if you need to integrate it into a page that is also managed by Django-CMS, it's possible to hook another app's URL patterns to that page by creating a CMS App Hook.